# how to get python code to loop to next page properly when scraping a website?

Tags: python

i am trying to scrape a real estate website but I am having issues getting my code to go to the next page(25 pages total). Currently, it is just continuously scraping page 1. I am a pretty big newb at this so apologies if this is a dumb request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

base_url = 'https://www.rew.ca/properties/areas/kelowna-bc'

for i in range(1,26):
    url = '/page/' + str(i)

    while url:
        response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        listings = soup.find_all("article")

        with open("property4.csv", "w") as csv_file:
            csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow(["title", "type", "price", "location", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "square feet", "link"])
        for listing in listings:
            location = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-info").get_text().strip()
            price = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-title hidden-xs").get_text().strip()
            link = listing.find("a").get('href').strip()
            title = listing.find("a").get('title').strip()
            type = (listing.find(class_="clearfix hidden-xs").find(class_="displaypanel-info")).get_text()
            bedrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[2]).get_text()
            bathrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[3]).get_text()
            square_feet = (listing.find_all("li")[4]).get_text()
            csv_writer.writerow([title, type, price, location, bedrooms, bathrooms, square_feet, link])
            next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control")
            url = next_btn.find("a")["href"]
```

Comment: `url = next_btn.find("a")["href"]` is quite a broad match. Can you confirm that it isn't finding a link back to page 1?

Comment: Your are calling ```soup.find(class="paginator....")``` but isn't soup the full document so it will always return a button if it's there? It's hard to tell because you code is crashing when I run it because it is trying to access a non-existent element but that could just be me.

Comment: I can't seem to find it again on the last page. I think the issue is next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control") is still on the last page even though the button isn't operational. Not sure if that made sense or not?

Comment: @sin tribu soup is the full document but I thought my code was dynamic enough to get the document for each respective page?

Comment: It is my mistake, but is your code crashing? When I print url after ```url=next_btn.find('a')['href']``` I get ```/properties/areas/kelowna-bc/page/2```, but the ```/properties/areas/kelowna-bc/``` is already part of the base_url, so if it is crashing then fix that. If it is stuck in the loop then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You had two issues with your loop.

1. Indentation

The indentation of the  `find()` statement, made the code find the button multiple times per page, that is unnecessary.

2. while loop

The while loop stops you from progressing from page 1 to 2, since url is true even when you have found the next page. Simply remove that.

Here is a fixed version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

base_url = 'https://www.rew.ca/properties/areas/kelowna-bc'

for i in range(1,26):
    url = '/page/' + str(i)

    response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    listings = soup.find_all("article")        
    #do you csv work here
    next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control")
    url = next_btn.find("a")["href"]
    print(url)
```

To develop your code a bit, I then broke out the csv logic intoa function, and used a while loop instead of for loop. The benefit of this, is that you dont need to update the loop if more listings make the pagination longer or shorter.

As I tried my code out, I found that the domain asks that you don't request faster than one page per 5 seconds, so I added a 5 second delay between scrapes

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def parse_listing(page_html):
  listings = soup.find_all("article")
  with open("property4.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["title", "type", "price", "location", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "square feet", "link"])

  for listing in listings:
    location = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-info").get_text().strip()
    price = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-title hidden-xs").get_text().strip()
    link = listing.find("a").get('href').strip()
    title = listing.find("a").get('title').strip()
    type = (listing.find(class_="clearfix hidden-xs").find(class_="displaypanel-info")).get_text()
    bedrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[2]).get_text()
    bathrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[3]).get_text()
    square_feet = (listing.find_all("li")[4]).get_text()
    csv_writer.writerow([title, type, price, location, bedrooms, bathrooms, square_feet, link])

prefix = 'https://www.rew.ca'
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.rew.ca/properties/areas/kelowna-bc').text, 'html.parser')

while True:
  parse_listing(d)
  next_page=d.find('a', {'rel': 'next'})
  if next_page:
      href_link=next_page.get('href')
      print(href_link)
      d= soup(requests.get(prefix + href_link).text, 'html.parser')
      time.sleep(5)
  else:
      print("no more 'next page'")
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work. It's not pretty, but hopefully it helps you see how it's rotating through the pages.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import time

## use the actual base url since url returned from the page is /properties/areas/kelowna-bc/page/XX 
base_url = 'https://www.rew.ca'
url = '/properties/areas/kelowna-bc/page/1'

with open("property4.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["title", "type", "price", "location", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "square feet", "link"])
    while url:
        time.sleep(5) ## not sure how slow to make this but the site will start returning 429 if you scrape too fast.
        response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
        print(f"{response}, {response.url}")  # debugging -- helps show what page was actually requested.
        response.raise_for_status() # this will raise an exception if we don't get a 200 returned.

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        listings = soup.find_all("article")
        for listing in listings:
            location = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-info").get_text().strip().split() ## you'll need to decide how to handle these
            price = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-title hidden-xs").get_text().strip()
            link = listing.find("a").get('href').strip()
            title = listing.find("a").get('title').strip()
            type = (listing.find(class_="clearfix hidden-xs").find(class_="displaypanel-info")).get_text()

            # not all listings contain bathroom and squarefootage 
            parts = listing.find_all("li")
            bedrooms = (parts[2]).get_text() if len(parts) >= 3 else None
            bathrooms = (parts[3]).get_text() if len(parts) >= 4 else None
            square_feet = (parts[4]).get_text() if len(parts) >= 5 else None
            csv_writer.writerow([title, type, price, location, bedrooms, bathrooms, square_feet, link])
            print(f"{title:<45} {type:<15} {price:<10} bath {bathrooms} Sqft {square_feet}")
        next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control")
        next_link = next_btn.find("a")
        url = next_link['href'] if next_link else None
```